# How to record all the possible values of public static fields during test suite execution?

Tags: java, serialization, jvm, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

Firstly, this question is more like a general question than a specific technical problem.

I'm doing a research project, where I need to record all the possible values of public static fields during the test suite execution (The project to run the test suite can be any projects, not written by me, and preferably not change its code). To do this, my plan was to detect the value changes of such public static fields and then serialize those values at the same time.

Specifically, I wanted to use ASM to instrument the java class files to detect such (public-static-)variable-changing instructions and insert some instructions to do the serialization.

However, I noticed that "detect the value change of such public static fields" can be hard and tricky. It is not simply monitoring the `PUTSTATIC` instruction, because `PUTSTATIC` only means the reference of that variable is changed (if it is an object), but actually the state (value) of the public static objects can be changed in various ways, e.g., `List.add(xxx)`, `List.remove(xxx)`, and even other user-defined functions of user-defined classes.

For example:

```java
class Name {
    String firstName;
    String familyName;
    public Name(String firstName, String familyName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.familyName = familyName;
    }
}

class Person {
    Name name;
    public Person(Name name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class Test {
    // The following value change (static initializer) can be detected by monitoring 'PUTSTATIC'
    public static Person president = new Person(new Name("foo", "bar"));
    public void personTest(){
        // The object (reference) changed, can be detected by monitoring 'PUTSTATIC'
        president = new Person(new Name("xxx", "yyy"));
        // The object state changed, but can not be detected by monitoring 'PUTSTATIC'
        president.name = new Name("a", "b");
        president.name.familyName = "c";
        ...
    }
}
```

I'm not sure whether it is possible to "record all the possible values of public static fields during test suite execution". Any ideas about this?

Comment: This is not possible, due to the halting problem. Note that you're delving real deep here. Is it 'a change' if I call `someStaticField.foo()`, where foo() just causes a log message to be emitted? No? What if foo() deletes a file. Before you say no, note that there is no effective difference between a `public static boolean` field, and deleting/creating a file in a specific location. So why does one 'count' and the other 'does not'?

Comment: What if I call a method that changes a 'builder' state, but then this builder isn't used? You've changed a property that has no effect. This turns essentially philosophical - if a tree falls in the forest, and all that. Turns out, the definition of 'track changes' requires that you define what the word __change__ means. And this is not, at all, obvious.

Comment: Does calling `String.hashCode()` change the String? It may assign the `hashCode` field when first called, after all.

Comment: You’d simplify your task by using immutable types, e.g. `record Name(String firstName, String familyName) {}`, however, it’s not clear why “serialize every possible state” is an actual goal. If I do `president.name.familyName = "x"; president.name.firstName = "y";`, the intermediate state of having `"x"` for the `familyName` but the old `firstName` would last only for some nanoseconds if the serialization wasn’t slowing everything down, so what’s the point of serializing it? I could even go a step further and ask, what’s the significance of `static` fields in your application?